# Will the files be deleted on app update?

Tags: android

I want to create a settings file for my app which I store in the internal memory. I am wondering if this file will be deleted when the user updates the app to a newer version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No they are only deleted on uninstall. You want to look into [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) though for storing basic preferences.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that part.